# Pandas, subtract values based on value of another column

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas, I'm trying to figure out how to generate a column that is the difference between the time of the current row and time of the last row in which the value of another column is True:

So given the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':[5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50],
            'Event_Occured': [True,False,False,True,True,False,False,True,False,False]})

print df

  Event_Occured  Time
0          True     5
1         False    10
2         False    15
3          True    20
4          True    25
5         False    30
6         False    35
7          True    40
8         False    45
9         False    50
```

I'm trying to generate a column that would look like this:

```
  Event_Occured  Time  Time_since_last
0          True     5                0
1         False    10                5
2         False    15               10
3          True    20                0
4          True    25                0
5         False    30                5
6         False    35               10
7          True    40                0
8         False    45                5
9         False    50               10
```

Thanks very much!

​

Comment: Please show us the steps you have tried so far and where exactly you are failing to achieve the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative that fills the values corresponding to Falses with the last valid observation:

```
df['Time'] - df.loc[df['Event_Occured'], 'Time'].reindex(df.index).ffill()
Out: 
0     0.0
1     5.0
2    10.0
3     0.0
4     0.0
5     5.0
6    10.0
7     0.0
8     5.0
9    10.0
Name: Time, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `df.Event_Occured.cumsum()` gives you distinct groups to `groupby`.  Then applying a function per group that subtracts the first member's value from every member gets you what you want.

```
df['Time_since_last'] = \
    df.groupby(df.Event_Occured.cumsum()).Time.apply(lambda x: x - x.iloc[0])

df
```

[image]